# Unexpected concatenation of shell variables

Tags: shell

When I try executing the following lines of code on shell-

```
#!/bin/sh
mc=XX:XX:XX:XX; dd bs=1 count=2 if=/dev/random 2>/dev/null |hexdump -v -e '/1 ":%02X"'
echo $mc
```

the output I get is

```
:04:CCXX:XX:XX:XX
```

,i.e. the **X's are concatenated at the end instead of the beginning**. I also tried this (as mentioned in an answer on SO ) -

```
#!/bin/sh
mc=XX:XX:XX:XX
mc=$mc dd bs=1 count=2 if=/dev/random 2>/dev/null |hexdump -v -e '/1 ":%02X"'
echo $mc
```

I still get the same output. What am I missing here ? I am a shell novice so please forgive me for any obvious mistakes

Comment: Why do you expect the output from `echo` to occur anywhere else than after the output from the commands which precede it?  When and how you assign a value to `mc` has no bearing on when the `echo` of its value executes.  Scripts are evaluated from top to bottom; the `echo` comes after the `dd | hexdump`.  Anyway, it's not clear what you are attempting to accomplish or how you expect that to happen -- maybe expand on what you want to do and how this code is supposed to facilitate that.

Comment: I am trying to generate random MAC addresses using the above code. The XX:XX:XX:XX indicate the fixed part, which will be fixed for any new address generated, and remaining part of the address will be generated randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a subshell to put the output of the command in `mc`, not a comma that executes the command and writes its output to stdout *after* `mc` has been assigned something and *before* you write `mc` to stdout:

```
#!/bin/sh
mc=XX:XX:XX:XX$(dd bs=1 count=2 if=/dev/random 2>/dev/null |hexdump -v -e '/1 ":%02X"')
echo $mc
```

Explanation: `var=$(cmd)` puts what `cmd` writes on stdout in the `var` variable. As `hexdump` writes to stdout, you have to write `var=foo:$(hexdump)` to concatenate the output of `hexdump` *after* `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hoping that `mc=some commands` will put the output of `some commands` in the variable `mc`, that's not how it works.  The correct syntax for that is `mc=$(some commands)`.

The meaning of `mc=some commands` is that `mc=some` is assigned for the duration of `commands`, and then `mc` returns to its old value when `commands` finishes.

Incidentally, you should quote the final value unless you specifically require the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion of the value.  `echo "$mc"` with double quotes around the variable interpolation.